# Objective c - Flip animations with 2 subviews

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, flip

I have an `UIView` with a pic inside (65x65) and I want to "flip" this `UIView` with a blank `UIView` but it doesn't work. I only can flip my view with the same view, when I'm adding the blank view, it works but not with the flip animation.

Here is my code who works :

```
   [UIView transitionWithView:myView
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    //[myView removeFromSuperview];
                    // [self.view addSubview:tmp];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    [myView removeFromSuperview];
                }];
```

The commented part is what I was trying to do, "tmp" is the blank UIView (init with `myView.frame`) and of course I remove the line in the "completion" part.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[UIView transitionFromView:myView toView:tmp duration:0.5  
  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [myView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```